# python 変数 for i inの計算

Tags: python

aという変数の値には[1,2,3,4,5]という値が入っていて前から三番目まで足して割る.いわゆる平均の値表示(b)させたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.append(a[i] + a[i]/3)
x = a.arange(0, len(dates[0]))  

print(b)
```

Comment: 質問文の説明とプログラムの内容とが噛み合っていないように見えます。プログラムの方は「配列のすべての要素を累乗して配列に追加…」になっていますよね？もう1点、関連質問を含め`json`のタグがついていますが、質問本文を読む限り直接の関連が不明です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。配列の3番目までの平均を取り出したいです。コードのほうが間違っていると思います

Comment: ご質問の本題とは関係ありませんが、このコードはそのままだとエラーになります。`if __name__ == "__main__":` のあとにインデントが無いため、if 文の中のプログラムが存在しないことになるからです。コード部分の装飾を間違えていらっしゃいませんか？　プログラムをペーストし直して、コード全体を範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` を押すと一括で自動整形できますので、お試しください。

Comment: 「うまくいきません」とありますが、できれば「期待する動作」と「実際の動作」の両方をご説明頂けませんか？　「うまくいかない」にも、エラーが出るだとか出力が違うだとか色々あるため、ご説明頂けると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 1):

こんなんどうでしょうか。

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    target = a[:3]              #=> [1, 2, 3]
    s = sum(target)
    l = len(target)
    b = s / l

    print(b)
```

Comment: この回答を読む初学者の為のコメント： `b = s / l` が正常に動くのはpython3のみです（python2だと整数に丸められてしまうので、 `b = float(s) / float(l)` や `b = s / (l * 1.0)` という記述をする必要があります）